# Not getting transactResponse event when using IFrameCommunicator (sandbox)

Tags: authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net hosted payment page in sandbox using iframe method. I implemented IFrameCommunicator mechanism to receive messages. My page gets resize events and cancel event. I am not getting transactResponse event on completed transaction.

Wondering whether transactResponse event is available in the sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0):

you should set 'hostedProfileIFrameCommunicatorUrl' value. eg:

```
$setting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
$setting->setSettingName("hostedProfileIFrameCommunicatorUrl");
$url = 'your url';
$setting->setSettingValue($url);
$request->addToHostedProfileSettings($setting);
$controller = new AnetController\GetHostedProfilePageController($request);
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

```html
function callParentFunction(str) {
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    var s = {qstr : str , parent : referrer};
    //console.log(s);  str include response .
    if(referrer == 'https://test.authorize.net/customer/addPayment'){
        switch(str){
            case 'action=successfulSave' :
                //your code
                break;
        }
    }
}

function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event && event.data) {
        callParentFunction(event.data);
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
}

if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.length > 1) {
    callParentFunction(window.location.hash.substring(1));
}
```